# EMV select application returning "Function not supported"

Tags: smartcard, emv

I'm experimenting with EMV and I have a card which is giving back an unexpected result:

```
SELECT PPSE: 00a404000e325041592e5359532e444446303100
RESPONSE (9000): 6f32840e325041592e5359532e4444463031a520bf0c1d611b4f07a0000000032010500d5669736120456c656374726f6e870101
SELECT AID: 00a4040007a000000003201000
RESPONSE: 6A81 (Function not supported)
```

I'm using the same commands (of course changing AIDs) and I get a 9000 as expected, except for another card that gives back a 6985 (Conditions of use not satisfied).

Can anybody explain me in which cases the card returns these two error codes? It seems very weird that I get these errors just during the application selection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the card is blocked, in that case, the terminal will immediately terminate the session.

[image]